# Erro ao consumir API no Android

Tags: android, web-service, api

Estou tentando consumir uma API no Android, mas não estou conseguindo. Debugando parece que ele não consegue sair do AsyncTask e não retorna o valor para onde está chamando o método. Ele consegue ler os dados sem problema nenhum e atribuir true ou false para a variável, porém não retorna. Segue o código:

```
 private Boolean resultEntradaSetor;


public Boolean entradaSetor(final String numberOF){


    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.11/ws/entradaSetor.php?numberOF="+numberOF);
                HttpURLConnection myConnection =
                        (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    InputStream responseBody = myConnection.getInputStream();

                    InputStreamReader responseBodyReader =
                            new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8");

                    BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8"));
                    StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String inputStr;
                    while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                        responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseStrBuilder.toString());

                    if(jsonArray.length() == 0)
                        resultEntradaSetor = false;
                    else
                        resultEntradaSetor = true;

                    myConnection.disconnect();
                } else {
                    // Error handling code goes here
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return resultEntradaSetor;
}
```

}

Comment: Eu criei um método separado para o AsyncTask e deu certo, porém eu preciso que diferentes conexões seja feita, como passo parâmetro para ele de acordo com a minha necessidade?

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma classe separada, e passe os parâmetros pelo construtor, se for mais de um. Por exemplo:

**Chamada**

```
AsyncTaskEntrada entradaTask = new AsyncTaskEntrada("http://192.168.1.11/ws/entradaSetor.php?numberOF=", numberOF);
entradaTask.execute();
```

**AsyncTask class**

public class AsyncTaskEntrada extends android.os.AsyncTask {

```
private URL url;
private String numberOf;
private Boolean resultEntradaSetor;

public AsyncTaskEntrada(URL url, String numberOf) {
    this.url = url;
    this.numberOf = numberOf;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    HttpURLConnection myConnection = null;
    try {
        myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (myConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            InputStream responseBody = myConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader responseBodyReader =
                    new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8");

            BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseBody, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String inputStr;
            while ((inputStr = streamReader.readLine()) != null)
                responseStrBuilder.append(inputStr);

            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseStrBuilder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (jsonArray.length() == 0)
                resultEntradaSetor = false;
            else
                resultEntradaSetor = true;

            myConnection.disconnect();
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultEntradaSetor;
}
```

}